# PDF.js Message : Unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm still fairly new to PDF.js. I'm trying to link my viewer.html with my pdf which are located in another server, eg: 100.0.55.10. Code shown below is how I embed the pdf in my iframe.

```html
//LocalDir = http:///127.0.0.1/Main/Apps/Document/web
//BookLoc = http:///100.0.55.10/pdfFolder/pdfname.pdf

<iframe id="framePDF" name="framePDF" src="#LocalDir#/viewer.html?file=#BookLoc#" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

I've managed to go around the issue with CORS by changing the mode in viewer.js to 'no-cors'. However, now it can't retrieved the pdf from the server 100.0.55.10.

[image: Console error]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution suggested here? It sounds like you might be able to resolve it with additional CORS configuration: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/4530

There's some good information in the FAQ for PDF.js: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-xhr